# Polio certification for one week UK visit

Tags: uk, health, paperwork, pakistani-citizens

I'm a Pakistani citizen going to the UK for a week on a business visit. Do I need to have the polio certification?

Comment: No. 11 more to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> NO, you dont need to present a polio certificate at UK immigration

Answer is from official **https://ukvi-international.faq-help.com/** website:

> "   donotreply@hgs-ukvi.co.uk
>
> Thank you for contacting the UK Visas and Immigration International
>   enquiry service.
>
> **Based on your mentioned circumstances, you do not need to show your**
>   **polio vaccination certificate to the UK Border Control**.
>
> For any further details, or should you need to contact us again please
>   refer to our website at https://ukvi-international.faq-help.com/,
>   select appropriate country, click next and then select “E-Mail form
>   and complete as instructed. We will aim to come back to you within 1
>   day.
>
> Kind regards,
>
> Daranee
>
> United Kingdom Visas and Immigration International Enquiry Service

There are few Embassies and Consulates in Pakistan who still require polio certificate at application level. Once you obtain a visa, usually immigration don't ask polio certificate when you enter to their country.